# Acces data in jQuery Datatable Codebehind ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

Playing around with Datatable with Form API: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/form.html
Let's say I enter "Software" in the searchbox for the table, 6 entries will show in table.
When submitting the form by pressing the Submit button - how can I access the 6 entries in codebehind?

I have an identical setup in my Visual Studio and can't figure it out.

CODE (Default.aspx)

```
...
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" class="init">


            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example').dataTable().columnFilter();
            });


        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <label id="lblStatus" runat="server"></label>
        <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
        <div>

        <table width="100%" class="display" id="example" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
...
```

CODE: (Default.aspx.cs)

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack)
        {
            lblStatus.InnerText = "Postback!";
            lblStatus.InnerText = Request.Form[0].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Best regards

Comment: Can we see some code context?

Comment: Code added. 99% the same as from the example from Datatables

Comment: @user1281991 Doesn't matter if it's the exact same, your question must be self contained so that if that example goes away someone will still be able to understand your question.